# gunzip or decompress the file in perl and capture the file name in variable

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module

I have `9001_20150921113547_00041.xml.gz`, I want to gunzip it or you can say decompress it to  `9001_20150921113547_00041.xml`... I have many ways to do it in perl, I have use **system()**, **qw**, **qx** and **backtick** as well, it just decompress the file and stored the file in path but I want to store the new decompress file name to variable how Can I do that ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the filename like so:
`my $filename = '/my/file.xml';
system( "gunzip -c 9001_20150921113547_00041.xml.gz >$filename" );`

Comment: This works for me,. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Archive::Zip](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Archive-Zip-1.50/lib/Archive/Zip.pm) from CPAN to execute the job with all the bits under your control. Then you do not need to fork out an extra unzip command, and you control the output file name yourself. The documentation on that page also has code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try Perl module [IO::Uncompress::Unzip](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Unzip.html) - Read zip files/buffers:

> use IO::Uncompress::Unzip qw(unzip $UnzipError);
>
> my $z = new IO::Uncompress::Unzip $input [OPTS] 
>       or die "unzip failed: $UnzipError\n";